# "Call to std::pair is ambiguous" by Clion but code can be compiled

Tags: c++, windows, clion

I have a function that compiles in this state but gives "Call to pair is ambiguous" but only in Clion IDE, compiles without problem and the warning dissapears if i add whatever random thing, even if it ends up causing compiler error.

```
std::pair<Status, std::set<std::string>> Config::foo(const std::string &sec, const std::string &key) const {

    return std::pair<Status, std::set<std::string>>(
            hasSection(sec) ? (hasKey(sec, key) ? Status::Success 
                                                : Status::MissingKey)
                                 : Status::MissingSec ,
         hasKey(sec, key) ? config_map.find(sec)->second.find(key)->second 
                                   : std::set<std::string>()  
          );
}
```

I have no idea how to fix it, or even what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want constructs a pair object, you have to use std::make_pair function template.

`template <class T1, class T2>
  pair<V1,V2> make_pair (T1&& x, T2&& y);`

The template types can be implicitly deduced from the arguments passed to make_pair.

```
 return std::make_pair(
        hasSection(sec) ? (hasKey(sec, key) ? Status::Success
                                            : Status::MissingKey)
                             : Status::MissingSec ,
     hasKey(sec, key) ? config_map.find(sec)->second.find(key)->second : 
     std::set<std::string>()
      );
```

This code compile without "Call to pair is ambiguous".

If you specify the make_pair template type, you encounter an error of the type "Expression must be rvalue".

Comment: Zerg's code is correct, "Call to pair is ambiguous" is essentially a CLion bug. std::pair has an _initialization constructor_ that you use it so "`std::pair <std::string,int> example("example",2);`". std::make_pair, instead, build std::pair object  using _r-value_ and _move constructor_ (and implicit conversion).

Comment: I'd rather `return { a, b };`.